# How can I make window shadows larger than 18?

Tags: compiz

In `ccsm` under Window Management>Window Decoration>Shadow Radius, you can only slide up to 18.

If you use `gconf-editor` you used to be able to set any size under `/>compiz-1>general>screen0>options>shadow_radius`.

Any idea on how to increase it?

Comment: You still can change at his place: `/apps/compiz-1/plugins/decor/screen0/options/shadow_radius` example: `gconftool-2 --set --type=Float /apps/compiz-1/plugins/decor/screen0/options/shadow_radius 15` but it appears that even if you put higher than 18, it will expand only until 18.

Comment: I noticed that. I usually set it to about 45. 18 seems to be max no matter what.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: 11.04 with compiz 0.9.4

Answer (score 1):

If the shadow setting is in the theme you will have to edit it inside the theme.

How To Edit A Theme:

```
cd /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1
sudo nano metacity-theme-1.xml
```

Find the line (use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to search) that says:

```
<shadow radius=”45.0″ opacity=”0.75″ color=”#abde4f” x_offset=”1″ y_offset=”4″/
```

Change the radius to a value you can deal with… I chose 10.

Comment: Is that new in this version of compiz? I notice if I use the Ambiance theme the focused window has about a 45 shadow and the unfocused have about 8.  Where can I look for shadow adjustment in the theme. ~/.themes/mytheme/metacity-1/metacity-theme-1.xml ? What should I look for in the code?

Comment: this is the version of compiz that is included with Unity. I would look for the same details above.